# MySQL full-text search returning relevance score incorrectly

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I am doing full-text search in MySQLI. my MySQL query is like:

```
$query="(Select col1,col2,MATCH (Srch_String) AGAINST ('".$search."' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS relevance FROM table_name WHERE MATCH (Srch_String) AGAINST ('".$search."' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) ORDER BY relevance DESC)"; 
$run = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
```

in the 'Srch_String' column of database contain two rows:

[My database :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzI1L.jpg)

My database:

```
Row_1 => Thakur pap debe kintu jodi tui Habi jabi chinta vabna koris.
Row_2 => Habi jabi chinta vabna korte nei. Thakur kintu pap debe .
```

Now if I search for

```
$search ="thakur pap debe kintu";
```

I got the relevance score as:

```
row_id 1 => 14.566221237182617
and row_id 2 => 14.714920997619629
```

Both the row contain all the words in the string "thakur pap debe kintu". But it returning different results. Also, the first row contain the exact phrase *"thakur pap debe kintu"* but resulting in less relevance than second row.

**My question**: why does the row_id = 1 have less relevance than row_id 2 in the above case?

I'm using database engine MyISAM.

`Srch_String` column has collation `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`.

My search result is also case-insensitive.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3TqcnXfb7hLVV4C6uq8GbZ/0)

Comment: @PaulSpiegel change engine=MyISAM; I don't know how to change it  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3TqcnXfb7hLVV4C6uq8GbZ/0

Comment: Still I get a higher value for the first row: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vLxMCSmrUDbruFMf8yn6BQ/0

Comment: I have updated your DB Fiddle . See it ..https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vLxMCSmrUDbruFMf8yn6BQ/3

Comment: Aah.. My bad :-)

Comment: I bet [it's the length](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vLxMCSmrUDbruFMf8yn6BQ/4) - Which makes sence for me - becuase the shorter the string, the more relevant are the search terms in it.